# How to copy multiple files in directory and move each into their correct directory

Tags: path, directory, find, copy, cat

Unix shell ksh

I created a file list and am currently trying to copy each file to their correct path.

```
(mylist)
-1111
-2222
-3333
-4444
-5555
```

*current directory*
/sample/dir/unknown/

```
-1111fileneeded.txt
-2222fileneeded.txt
-3333fileneeded.txt
-4444fileneeded.txt
-5555fileneeded.txt
-6666dontneed.txt
-7777dontneed.txt
-8888dontneed.txt
...etc
```

The first 4 characters of each file matches with their correct path to where they need to go.

```
/sample/dir/1111/
/sample/dir/2222/
/sample/dir/3333/
/sample/dir/4444/
```

So here is what I currently have..

```
for i in `cat mylist`
do echo "$i"
 find /sample/dir/unknown/mylist*
```

this is where I am kinda stuck and trying to figure out what needs to be done to have each file moved into their correct directory.

Comment: What platform and shell are you using?

Comment: Apologies, yes i'm using Shell

Comment: /Which/ shell?  bash, csh, tcsh, sh, ...?

Comment: unix shell ksh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work

```
#!/bin/ksh
while IFS=\| read -r line; do
   dir=`echo $line | cut -c 2-5`
   mv "$line /sample/$dir/$line"
done > filelist.txt
```

`IFS` is escape special char, just in case.

`cut -c 2-5` is taking all char from 2 to 5 (because there is a dash at the start of your file name)

Let me know if there is something else you don't understand.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: If my answer helped can you upvote / accept it please ?

Comment: Hi Will, I accepted it, but i can't upvote this since I don't have enough rep to do that yet.  But many thanks!